# Exception handling issue in zend framework 2

Tags: exception, zend-framework2

try {

```
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('nonexistantclass');
} catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught exception: " . get_class($e) . "\n";
    echo "Message: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";

}
```

I'm using your above code for zend framework 2  in some  controller action method , after executing some line its getting blank , It seems that exception has been caused but why the its not displaying $e->getMessage() content . Do i need to use any name space for using  this , or what is the correct way to use Exception Handling in zend framework 2 . Please help me

Comment: I strongly recommend reading about Autoloading Process and role of the Namespaces in ZF2 before trying to do something via un-usual ways. https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html

Comment: Hey @foozy , actually i want to use exception handling in my code in zend framework 2 , so i found from there website  http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.exception.html , I have just used the above code jucst to check whether it is working or not , I guess it is not working , may be ihave done some mistakes , but unable to trace it .

Comment: The classes you use are Zend Framework 1 - not 2. For using ZF2, simply follow the guidelines of the documentation and make yourself comfortable using composer. PHP Development without composer will only become less fun in the future.

Comment: Hey Sam the above code was given in zend framework 2 tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to provide a sample code.

It should be -

```
try {
     $model = new NonExistantClass(); //Any code that will throw an Exception.
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Message: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The `\` backslash before the `Exception $e` states that the Class is not under the namespace mentioned at the top of the page but its the core PHP class.

Comment: Hi @Kunal Dethe i tried your code  , but still didnt worked  , giving this error => Fatal error: Class 'Front\Controller\NonExistantClass' not found in /var/www/zf2-tutorial/module/Front/src/Front/Controller/LoginController.php on line 107 . I'm running my code in my local machine